# Extend attrbiute instead of setting it?

Tags: xslt

I'm building a quite complex XSLT in order to generate some HTML markup.

On one my goal is to "extend" the `class` attribute of the generated markup using some templates.

Unfortunately, it does not works, because the XSLT tag `<xsl:attribute>` is only able to "set" attribute. Not to manipulate existing ones.

When I try, the original attribute is wiped.

Here is a small reproduction:

XML:

```
<node>
    <item value="1" type="abc"/>
    <item value="20" type="zxy"/>
</node>
```

XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="no"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="/node/item">
    <p class="{@type}">
      <xsl:call-template name='rule1' />
      <xsl:call-template name='rule2' />
    </p>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template name='rule1'>
    <xsl:attribute name='class'>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="@value mod 2 = 0">alpha</xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>omega</xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template name='rule2'>
    <xsl:attribute name='class'>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="@value mod 10 = 0">beta</xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>gamma</xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I would like to output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<p class="abc omega"/>
<p class="zxy beta alpha"/>
```

But it outputs

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<p class="omega"/>
<p class="beta"/>
```

is it possible to preserve the original attribute, or retrieve it within the utility template to reuse it?

Comment: Cant you set an xsl:variable to reuse it later? (Such as setting @type as the variable and then set the new attribute to "concat(variablename, appends)? Im not super comfortable with xslt yet but that in my mind would work.

Comment: A variable in xslt cannot be set multiple times. It's not apparent in my snippet above, but I will chain template to check for multiple business rules and apply multiple class to my node. If I work with variable, I still will have to declare at least one variable per template call.

Comment: I've update my snippet to include multiples templates

Comment: It can't be dynamically updated but it can be repopulated each time the template is called each time a node that matches that template is found in the xml.

Comment: Infact can't you just do `<xsl:value-of select="concat(@type, ' appends')"/>` as in, wont the `@type` (or the XPath for the parent node if you go deeper) still be what was in their previously?

Comment: Sorry, I see what you mean now about the class constantly being iterated upon. I can see how that would make the variable answer incorrect. Seems im out of my coding jurisdiction hah

Comment: np, thx to put me on the right track :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An approaching solution could be (thanks to @aleski suggestions)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="no"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="/node/item">
    <p>
    <xsl:attribute name='class'>
      <xsl:value-of select="@type" />
      <xsl:call-template name='rule1' />
      <xsl:call-template name='rule2' />
    </xsl:attribute>
    </p>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template name='rule1'>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="@value mod 2 = 0"><xsl:value-of select="' alpha'" /></xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="' omega'" /></xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template name='rule2'>

      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="@value mod 10 = 0"><xsl:value-of select="' beta'" /></xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="' gamma'" /></xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>

  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

It would seem that this answer would only satisfy a single deep, non-reiterated-upon class.
Include this at the start of the template you are calling:

```
<xsl:variable name="type" select="@type"/>
```

And then when it comes to updating the attribute value, try:

```
<xsl:attribute select="class">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="@value mod 2 = 0">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat($type, ' alpha')"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat($type, ' omega')"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:attribute>
```

Again, I'm not super comfortable with XSLT but I did just try something similar in a test recently and it worked a charm. Hope it helps.

EDIT: I'm not sure but you might have to put the escaped value for a "space" in the concat function, I forget.

Answer (score 0):

Do you like obscure coding solutions? If so, you can re-write your solution as this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="no"/>

  <xsl:template match="/node/item">
    <p class="{@type} {substring('alphaomega', 1 + 5 * (@value mod 2 = 0), 5)} {normalize-space(substring('beta gamma', 1 + 5 * (@value mod 10 = 0), 5))}">
    </p>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So, have three Attribute Value Templates in one attribute. If you take a look at one of them...

```
{substring('alphaomega', 1 + 5 * (@value mod 10 = 0), 5)}
```

This takes advantage of the fact that "true" evaluates to 1 in a numeric expression, and "false" evaluates to 0. So, when the expression is true, the first five characters of the string are returned. When it is false, the next five characters are.

Comment: this will break the purpose of having something simple, reusable and kinda plugable. thx anyway